# Range validation attribute returns false alert for a valid date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, date-range

My model holds two date properties.
that i want to limit their date range, so i place a data annotation attribute to validate it.

```
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "FaultOpenDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1900-01-01", "2500-01-01", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
        public DateTime FaultOpenDateTime { get; set; }

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "FaultCloseDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1900-01-01", "2500-01-01", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
        public DateTime FaultCloseDateTime { get; set; }
```

but the client side validation displays invalid for any valid date ... 
what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: In what format did you provide date - Invariant or maybe your local country?

Comment: @SławomirRosiek The format was DD/MM/YYY and i use jQuery date-picker to select and format it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default date's format expected by ASP.NET MVC and jQuery Validate is MM/DD/YYYY. If you want use format of specific culture:

1. Add to your `<system.web` in web.config the following section:

   `<globalization uiCulture="pl-PL" culture="pl-PL"/>`

   This will setup server-side culture of your web application
2. Use [jQuery Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) plugin to support that culture on client-side and override default validators for date that expect MM/DD/YYYY format. You should also override range validator.

   ```
   Globalize.culture('pl-PL');
   jQuery.validator.methods['date'] = function (value, element) {
       return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value);
   };
   jQuery.validator.methods['range'] = function (value, element, param) {
       var parsedValue = Globalize.parseDate(value) || Globalize.parseFloat(value),
           parsedParam1 = Globalize.parseDate(param[0]) || Globalize.parseFloat(param[0]),
           parsedParam2 = Globalize.parseDate(param[1]) || Globalize.parseFloat(param[1]);
       return this.optional(element) || (parsedValue >= parsedParam1 && parsedValue <= parsedParam2);
   };
   ```
3. Look also [how to setup format](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) in jQuery Date Picker

Comment: I have a dual language support that comes with two cultures how can i make the solution above dynamic according to the current thread culture ?

Comment: Ignore first step and in second step just get culture code from CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name

Comment: Sorry but it do not understand what the Globalization plugin has to do with the validation format.. is that the only way to tell the jquery validator that i use a different format ? and with regards to sstep 3 i already used the format of the datepicker to set it to DD/MM/YYY

Comment: In second step I just override existing date validator with new that use Globalization plugin. You can use your own logic to check if passed value is correct date. Default implementation of date validator check result of <code>new Date(value)</code>

Comment: Sorry but this is not working for me .. i have place the code from line two with the jQuery globalization ParseDate method and placed a debugger but it never fires... any other thoughts ?

Comment: I have even tried to set the date format to mm/dd/yy but the validator still miss-behaves ..

Comment: Okay for some reason it fires the Range validator for numbers .. how can i tell it that these are dates .. ?

Comment: What is your view? Did you have `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FaultOpenDateTime)`?

Comment: Did you mean client-side validation or server-side?

Comment: You must override all culture-sensitive validators that you want to use - range validator too